# Removing grid lines from vector layer using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have merged 2 vector layers  but i'm getting the vertical line or grid line.

How do I remove it?

This is the image where I highlighted the vertical line:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Do you have narrow gaps in between the grid lines?

Comment: I deleted my answer, because it is now narrowed to ArcGIS Software. Feel free to put a new question, if you decide to try QGIS also.

Comment: @BERA Yes there is narrow gap between layers. After merging those gaps cannot be seen. They Display as a line.

Comment: Is that your only gap, then you could edit and manually close it.

Comment: Yes the gaps is all trough that vertical line as i shown in above fig. Is there any automated way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

Use [Dissolve](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/dissolve.htm):

> Aggregates features based on specified attributes

With your land use class or whatever it is as `Dissolve field`

Comment: @ BERA  yes there is narrow gap. How to over come this issue. kindly give your inputs